# React propTypes errors not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm having problems with React propTyoes. I'v created a component that require 2 props to work as you guys can see in the code below.

When I use the component in the **App** file, passing just 1 prop, without the "stateSidebarVisible" it doesn't throw me any error/warning from react...
(I read a lot of things about the NODE_ENV production/development, I searched in my node for process.env and didnt found the NODE_ENV variable by the way).
Any clue?

**FFMainHeader**

```
export default class FFMainHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {...}
}

FFMainHeader.propTypes = {
  stateSidebarVisible: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  handleSidebarChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

**App**

This is where i call the FFMainHeader component.

```
export default class FFMainApp extends React.Component {
    .......
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="FFMainApp">
                <FFMainHeader
                    handleSidebarChange={this.onSidebarChange} />
                <FFMainSidebar />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
export default class FFMainHeader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickSidebarChange = this.clickSidebarChange.bind(this);
  }

  clickSidebarChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (this.props.stateSidebarVisible) ?
      this.props.stateSidebarVisible = false :
      this.props.stateSidebarVisible = true;
    this.props.handleSidebarChange(this.props.stateSidebarVisible);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header id="FFMainHeader">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.clickSidebarChange}>
          Abre/Fecha
        </a>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

FFMainHeader.propTypes = {
  stateSidebarVisible: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  handleSidebarChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: How did you perform "searched in my node"? You'd have to look through the source of node.js itself to find that. React is using internal `__DEV__` value, which is set using `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`. Usually, the `process.env.NODE_ENV` is explicitly exported using the `webpack.DefinePlugin`. Also, if you're using minified version of React, the propTypes warnings will not be shown.

Comment: I searched in node using "process.env" in my prompt it list me all envs i guess? I'm using systemjs instead webpack, using gulp/babel to transpile the files. When i run "process.env.NODE_ENV" in my gulp it will always return !== 'production' because it is undefined...

Comment: Can you provide the complete code of `<FFMainHeader />`?

Comment: Edited with the code @PraneshRavi, also i found a way to set the NODE_ENV using `NODE_ENV=development` before my gulp command
`NODE_ENV=development gulp dev` like that

Comment: Still not working, so if anyone know where can i find the answer...